# How to map Alamofire 5.2 response with ObjectMapper in Swift5

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, objectmapper, alamofire5

I have a model like this:

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

struct Token: Mappable {

    var token: String?
    var deviceId: String?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }


   mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        token <- map["token"]
        deviceId <- map["device_id"]
    }

}
```

So send a request with **Alamofire** like this:

```
import ObjectMapper
import Alamofire
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = ...
    AF.request(request).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { (response:AFDataResponse<Any>) in

               let token = Mapper<Token>().map(JSONString: serviceResponse.value) ‌//Not work   


   }
}
```

When print my response that is correct but, I can't map it to my object model with **ObjectMapper**.

Comment: Since Swift 4 `ObjectMapper` has become obsolete in favor of built-in `Codable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need return Value:

```
    func getUserMapple(completionHandler: @escaping (_ userData: UserMappable) -> ()) {
        
        guard let urlString = URL(string: userUrl) else { return }
        
        AF.request(urlString).responseJSON { (responce) in
            
            switch responce.result {
            case .success(let value):
                guard let castingValue = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let userData = Mapper<UserMappable>().map(JSON: castingValue) else { return }
            completionHandler(userData)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
  }
```

If you need return Array:

```
    func getUserMapple(completionHandler: @escaping (_ dotaData: [DotaModelMapable]) -> ()) {
        
        guard let urlString = URL(string: dotaUrl) else { return }
        
        AF.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                guard let dotaData = Mapper<DotaModelMapable>().mapArray(JSONObject: value) else { return }
                completionHandler(dotaData)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
  }
```